# Azure Functions 2.0: How to start a project from command prompt and allow connection from other machines?

Tags: azure-functions

I am developing an Azure Functions 2 Project, when using Visual Studio 2017 and Run, it Works like this:
[image: dotnet Azure Functions]

1) **What is the command line and proper parameters to launch the Azure Function Project DLL ?**
How can I run this same via command prompt (outside Visual Studio)?

2) **How to accept connections from other machines, not only localhost?**
I want that it accepts like ASP.Net Core (.UseUrls("http://+:7071")):

```
Now listening on: http://[::]:7071
```

but it is only listening on

```
http://localhost:7071
```

I am Azure fan, but I am asking this because I want to put a development version on a local server (on premisses), later when application grows I plan to publish to Azure; but now I don't want to install SQL Server on this server to run Azure Functions portal (Azure Functions Runtime)...

 
I don't want to install the Azure Functions portal. I just want to launch the Project, the same way Visual Studio 2017 does and accept connections from other computers, using the IP address or computer name.

Comment: `func host start` from `azure-functions-core-tools` npm package, not sure about external connections

Comment: Thanks, after installing NodeJS and running func start, the project worked local and on a server on this network. I got curious that before, when running in Visual Studio, I did not have NodeJS installed and could Run using F5. I still need to connect to it from other machines.

Comment: They both call `dotnet run` with proper parameters. You could probably do it manually from command line, if you really want to.

Comment: I think it is too much install NodeJS and azure-functions-core-tools npm package just to call dotnet run with proper parameters. :)

Comment: Could be, if that's your only usage of the tools

Comment: Why don't you publish to an azure site? Then other machines can call it (over the internet), and you get the power of the full azure functions portal (also running in the cloud, no local SQL installation necessary) .

Comment: I am Azure user, but on a customer they have a local datacenter so in this case for example I could use Azure Functions on premisses.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tested now and with the new version it works as I expected! 
Now I can easily run the Azure Functions on the Desktop and call the API on another device on my local network, also from my Mobile phone.

I updated to Visual Studio 2019 and the tools got updated to:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.6.1080 Commit hash: 509d59b7eb6fbfb89f70ce96ad22e00f8f7bafdd)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12427.0
```

Now on the console it appears:

```
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
```

[image: Screenshot]

To run the function from command line, outside Visual Studio, I did:

Install/update the tools:

```
npm install azure-functions-core-tools -g
```

Start the Azure Functions Host:

```
func host start
```

(I used npm 5.6.0, wich is installed with [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/))

Comment: I know this is old, but what command did you wind up using to launch the app from command line?  I'd like to be able to do this as well, launching several function apps as a batch script

Comment: I updated the answer to add the commands to install and start the Azure Functions Host (I tested using npm 5.6.0)

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  I was under the impression from reading the docs that you had to manually specify all the functions you wanted to launch, so it's good to see that's not the case

Comment: Thank you for simplifying this! You made my day of scouring the dotnet cli docs into just a few minutes. FYI if you wanna start multiple up at once, you need to specify a different port.
func host start --port 7072